# How to aggregate rows and create a pivoted table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
Start | End | Unit | Measure
-----------------------------
01    | 05  | GB   | 1
06    | 10  | GB   | 2
01    | 05  | MB   | 4
01    | 05  | GB   | 1
```

Unit column can contain three values KB, MB, and GB.

I want to create a new table with following attribute.

```
Start | End | KB | MB | GB
---------------------------
01    | 05  | 0  | 4  | 2
06    | 10  | 0  | 0  | 2
```

Measure for each corresponding units should be summed in the corresponding column, zeroing out where it is not present.

What is the best way to do it in Postgres, if the number of records I have is in millions? Doing it programmatically is very slow.

Answer (score 3):

Case `expression` for each unit should work:

[Click here for working SqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e810a/3)

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  Start_val CHAR(2),
  End_val  CHAR(2),
  Unit  CHAR(2),
  Measure INTEGER );

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('01', '05', 'GB', 1);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('06', '10', 'GB', 2);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('01', '05', 'MB', 4);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('01', '05', 'GB', 1);

CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT Start_val AS Start, 
       End_val AS End, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = 'KB' THEN Measure ELSE 0 END) AS KB, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = 'MB' THEN Measure ELSE 0 END) AS MB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = 'GB' THEN Measure ELSE 0 END) AS GB
FROM   test_table
WHERE Unit IN ('KB', 'MB', 'GB')
GROUP  BY Start_val,
          End_val
ORDER  BY Start_val; 

SELECT * FROM new_table;
```